# Angular FireStore Collections inside Documents

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a chat app in Angular 2, using Firebase FireStore Database.
I was able to create one `Collection`, with a `Docuement` for each 'message'. 
I used this code to retrieve the messages:

```js
export interface MessageItem {
  message: string;
  DateTime: Date;
  User: string;
}

messagesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<MessageItem>;
messages: Observable<MessageItem[]>;

getChatData() {
  this.messagesCollection = this.afs.collection<MessageItem>('chat_messages');
  this.messages = this.messagesCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

However, because I want multiple users, I would like to create a `Document` for each user, which stores inside a `Collection` of the messages.
This complicates it, and I'm not sure how to do it exactly.
I would be happy for some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

A route you may be able to take is instead of storing the collection of documents as 'Messages' you would want to create a collection of 'Conversations' and in each 'Conversation' document then have a simple array of 'DocumentReferences' that reference the two users in that conversation. You could also just store the UID's of each user and then fetch the user if necessary. Then, inside of the 'Conversation' document you would have a collection of messages between the two users. This is an approach I would take and if you need more assistance I can create the mockup service and data structure to show as an example. In short, storing the conversations first will help with the structure here.

Here is an example of how I would set up Firestore structure:

[image]

Here in the conversations collection I would store an Array of DocumentReferences to the users and then have a collection of Messages related to this conversation.

[image]

Now here in the users collection I would have a document for each user, where the Document Id is the UID from the authenticated User. This may seem redundant but I would also create a conversations collection in the user collection where each document only has a one field which is a DocumentReference to the conversation document. Here is an example of that document in the convos collection:

[image]

This way you stop users from being able to create duplicate conversation documents inside of the Conversations collection and you just need to make sure you save the conversation reference to each users convos collection after the conversation has been started.

When fetching the data from a service you would need to then snapshotChanges and grab that reference path and then request the conversation inside of your map function on the snapshot. Please let me know if you need guidance with the service after you have created this and setup your service with angularfire2.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly, each Collection will be a conversation. But how will the messages be stored, as a child collection in the conversation?

Comment: Yes, inside each 'Conversation' document you would have a collection of messages, each of which could have message, info about the message and then a DocumentReference to the user that sent that specific message as well. Richard Matsens answer above explains the JSON structure for this if you were to use Firebase RTDB. For Firestore this will just be nested collections inside of documents.

Comment: Also to clarify in your above comment, each 'Collection' will not be a conversation. You will have A 'Collection' of conversation documents which contain a collection of 'Messages'

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to go, but this [Build A Real-Time Chat App With VueJS, Vuex & Cloud Firestore](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/10/16/vue-js-firestore/) shows a fairly good implementation in vue.

This is their conversation document.

**Conversation structure**

```
{
  created: Date.now(),
  users: ['mr_a', 'mr_b'],
  messages: [
    { id: uuidv4(), text: 'Hi there', sender: 'mr_a', created: Date.now() },
    { id: uuidv4(), text: 'Hi to you too!', sender: 'mr_b', created: Date.now() }
  ]
}
```

For the mechanics of AngularFire2, see [Simple Chat App with AngularFire2 (Firebase + Angular 2)](https://github.com/designcourse/angularfire2-chat). It uses one conversation with messages as documents.

Comment: Thanks. That helps, although I'm still not sure how to build it exactly in Angular, what with Observables and such. For instance, how do I add a message to the messages array?

Comment: From the Vue example project, 'Firestore documents are updated using update(), which allows you to update certain fields, without touching the others.'. See [Add Data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)